# i have got ValueError: Input 0 of layer "lstm_10" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 186880)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network, lstm, reshape, prediction

### hi dear  I was running CNN-LSTM model after i reshape my dataset i have got this error

```
 ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-7a71cd756b29> in <cell line: 17>()
     15 
     16 # add LSTM layers
---> 17 model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu'))
     18 
     19 # add output layer

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
    233             ndim = shape.rank
    234             if ndim != spec.ndim:
--> 235                 raise ValueError(
    236                     f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" '
    237                     "is incompatible with the layer: "

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "lstm_10" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 186880)
```

i try this for reshape data

```
x_train = x_train.reshape((x_train.shape[0], 1, x_train.shape[1]))
x_test = x_test.reshape((x_test.shape[0], 1, x_test.shape[1]))

print (x_train.shape)
print (y_train.shape)
print (x_test.shape)
print (y_test.shape)
print (x_train.size)
print (x_test.size)
```

output was:
(5845, 1, 12)
(5845,)
(2505, 1, 12)
(2505,)
70140
30060

and for build my model i try this

from keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Flatten

```
# define the model
model = Sequential()
# add convolutional layers
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(x_train.shape[0], 1)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
# add LSTM layers
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu'))

# add output layer
model.add(Dense(1))

# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

---

but i have got the error that i sent in the first please help me if you could
`your text`